# How to change functions parameters view in vs code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In the latest updates to vs code it became as soon as you write the function or the method , the parameters automatically be written . I want to change it to make it like  number ( 2 ) in the image so that it appears only in a rectangle  like old versions .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using `JediLSP` Language Server? You can change to`Pylance` Language Server.

And for now, you can take `tab` to jump to the next parameter.